# Will the largest possible value of the dot product between a vector A and a mystery vector (x, y) of length 1 always be the magnitude of A?

Tags: linear-algebra

The question is pretty much all in the title, really.
I have a vector (2, 1) multiplied with (x, y) where the length of this vector is 1, and the largest possible value of the dot product is sqrt(5). Is it always this case?

Comment: $a\cdot b=||a||||b||\cos \theta$. In your case $||b||=1$, so you are correct.

Comment: @Vasting : You can use \Vert  instead of two copies of | to get better separation. Note $\Vert a\Vert \Vert b\Vert$ looks better than $||a||||b||$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because this is just the size of the projection of $A$ in the direction of $(x,y)$ (using the notation in the title). It is realized precisely when $A$ points in the same direction as $(x,y)$, up to sign.